# Access how to see the database mapping

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access base (v14) and i just want to see on a simple way what are the tables, the relation and maybe all others thing on this DB. Apparently we have an IHM too, and some VB macros maybe.
But i know nothing about access...

Comment: I'm guessing that "relationships" are not set up, as that would be one of the easiest ways to view, but again that does not necessarily show everything.   Go to each individual table and query and check out "Database Tools --> Object Dependencies" in the menu.  This should show the relationship between tables (and also forms that use the data).

Answer (score 0):

The [FMS Total Access Analyzer](http://fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/documentation/index.html) will show you everything at a glance.